# Refactor 3 methods to one which takes various arguments into one method

Tags: java, refactoring

I have these 3 methods which all have the same logic. The only difference is that a different parameter type is passed in:

```
public static String calculateAmount(QRequest qRequest) {

  if (qRequest.getValue() == null) {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }

  if (qRequest.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)
      && qRequest.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(600_CODE)) {
    throw new ServiceException("Multiple options received");
  }

  if (qRequest.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)) {
    return 125_VALUE;
  } else if (qRequest.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(600_CODE)) {
    return 600_VALUE;
  } else {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }
}

public static String calculateAmount(CState cState) {

  if (cState.getValue() == null) {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }

  if (cState.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)
      && cState
          .getValue()
          .getOptionalCodes()
          .contains(600_CODE)) {
    throw new ServiceException("Multiple options received");
  }

  if (cState.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)) {
    return 125_VALUE;
  } else if (cState
      .getValue()
      .getOptionalCodes()
      .contains(600_CODE)) {
    return 600_VALUE;
  } else {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }
}

public static String calculateAmount(RState rState) {

  if (rState.getValue() == null) {
    return EXCESS_300_VALUE;
  }

  if (rState.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)
      && rState
          .getValue()
          .getOptionalCodes()
          .contains(600_CODE)) {
    throw new ServiceException("Multiple options received");
  }

  if (rState.getValue().getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)) {
    return 125_VALUE;
  } else if (rState
      .getValue()
      .getOptionalCodes()
      .contains(600_CODE)) {
    return 600_VALUE;
  } else {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }
}
```

I thought I might be able to refactor it to something like `public static String calculateAmount(QRequest ... qRequest, CState ... cState, RState ... rState) {` then add some logic to the method to work out which type it is and proceed from there but that doesn't work.

An option which would work would be to refactor my `calculateAmount()` to accept a `Value` object and have 3 new methods, one which will accept each parameter type and extract the `Value` object.

Is it possible to refactor this so there's only one method which will accept any one of the 3 parameter types?

Comment: Create an Interface that contains the common methods (`getValue()` by the looks of it) of those 3 classes. Have your 3 classes implement that Interface and then you only need one single method that accepts an argument of that Interface.

Comment: Looking at your amount of points I assume that you can't change these types to implement an interface where you could just override some methods?

Comment: Another option would be to use an abstract class with the common logic

Comment: or reflection but it's not recommended

Comment: I second the notion of trying to introduce an interface if possible. If it isn't possible, it seems you might be able to create a common method that just takes the return value of `getValue()` (assuming it's the same type in each case) and the 3 original methods just call `getValue()` and pass that to the common method.

Comment: Are you able to modify the 3 classes? What type does their `getValue()` return?

Comment: Yes, I can modify the classes. `getValue()` returns a `Value` type

Comment: The first option of Thomas's answer "Introduce an interface" is the best way then.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment, I'd suggest the following options:

**Introduce an interface**

This allows you to write code which knows that whatever you pass is of type `HasValue` and thus has a `getValue()` method.

```
interface HasValue {
  ValueType getValue();
}

class QRequest implements HasValue { ... }
class CState implements HasValue { ... }
class RState implements HasValue { ... }

public static String calculateAmount(HasValue hasValue) {
  ValueType value = hasValue.getValue();
  if ( value  == null) {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }

  if ( value.getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)
    && value.getOptionalCodes().contains(600_CODE)) {
    throw new ServiceException("Multiple options received");
  }

  if (value.getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)) {
    return 125_VALUE;
  } else if (value.getOptionalCodes().contains(600_CODE)) {
    return 600_VALUE;
  } else {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }
}
```

**Introduce a helper method**

If you can't introduce a common interface for some reason you need to provide the overloads for each type. However, if their `getValue()` methods all return the same type (`ValueType` is a placeholder for it) then a helper method that just gets the value and operates on that.

```
public static String calculateAmount(QRequest qRequest) {
  return calculateAmountHelper(qRequest.getValue());
}

public static String calculateAmount(CState cState) {
  return calculateAmountHelper(cState.getValue());
}

public static String calculateAmount(RState rState) {
  return calculateAmountHelper(rState.getValue());
}

//or make it public and call this instead of the other 3 methods
private static String calculateAmountHelper(ValueType value) {
  if ( value  == null) {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }

  if ( value.getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)
    && value.getOptionalCodes().contains(600_CODE)) {
    throw new ServiceException("Multiple options received");
  }

  if (value.getOptionalCodes().contains(125_CODE)) {
    return 125_VALUE;
  } else if (value.getOptionalCodes().contains(600_CODE)) {
    return 600_VALUE;
  } else {
    return 300_VALUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Presumably in my 3 classes I must set `getValue()`. How is that done?

Comment: @runnerpaul I'm not sure I understand your question - "set getValue()" doesn't make much sense to me :) . If you make all 3 classes implement a common interface, e.g. `HasValue` in my example, then they will need to implement the methods in that interface - which they might already be doing if the signature and return types are the same in all 3 cases.